# how to bubble sort xlsx file

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, bubble-sort

so here I want to make a case study about bubble sort, where I sort from the smallest to the largest numbers ( Ascending ) whose data I get from the .xlsx file
and the number to be sorted is column h5-median
After the data is sorted, the other data will be sorted as well
the code that I made is running but not effective

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwui8.png)

````
```
import pandas as pd

rank = []
publication = []
index = []
median = []

df = pd.read_excel(r'data.xlsx')

for i in range(len(df)):
  rank.append(df.values[i][0])
  publication.append(df.values[i][1])
  index.append(df.values[i][2])
  median.append(df.values[i][3])

for i in range(1, len(rank)):
  for j in range((len(rank) -  i)):
    if (median[j] > median[j + 1]):
      tempRank = rank[j + 1]
      tempPub = publication[j + 1]
      tempInd = index[j + 1]
      tempMed = median[j + 1]

      rank[j + 1] = rank[j]
      publication[j + 1] = publication[j]
      index[j + 1] = index[j]
      median[j + 1] = median [j]

      rank[j] = tempRank
      publication[j] = tempPub
      index[j] = tempInd
      median[j] = tempMed

for i in range(len(rank)):
  print(rank[i], publication[i], index[i], median[i])
```
````

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not effective"?

Comment: I think the result of my code is too convoluted, so I want to make the code shorter or concise

Answer (score 0):

The specifics of what you are looking for is a bit unclear, but if all you need is a bubble sort algorithm and you do not want or need to implement it yourself you can just pip install the MIT licensed library [bubble-sorter](https://pypi.org/project/bubble-sorter/).

If you want the bubble sort algorithm to be implemented yourself but you are just trying to make the code "better," my suggestion would be to edit your question explaining what exactly is the problem you have with your current bubble sort code and describe how you envision a better version looking (in general), so that people here can better assist you.

Comment: I'm not going to upvote because it's not really an answer, but it's good advice regardless.